# Images only load when directly required and are inconsistent when required through another module

Tags: image, reactjs, react-native, mobile, rendering

## What is consistent

### [Edit: No longer consistent for whatever reason]

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-native';
import STYLE from './styles';

export default class OwnMarker extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Image 
                style={STYLE.marker} 
                source={require('../../../../resources/images/marker.png')}
                resizeMethod="resize"
            />
        );
   }
}
```

This results in a consistently working solution.
[image: Working Solution]

## What is inconsistent

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-native';
import STYLE from './styles';

//Note import
import Images from '../../../../resources/Images';

export default class OwnMarker extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Image 
                style={STYLE.marker} 
                source={Images.own_marker}
                resizeMethod="resize"
            />
        );
   }
}
```

And the imported object looks like this:

```
//Images.js
module.exports = {
    own_marker: require('./images/marker.png'),
}
```

This results in an inconsistent solution
[image: Not Working Solution]

Sometimes these images load and sometimes they don't. It might only render the image for 3 of the markers, none of them, all of them, 7 or them, or whatever other possibility between none and all of the markers loading.

How can I make this work from the import statement and why is it currently inconsistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to sleep at night with a solution like this, but this is the only one that has worked for me.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image} from 'react-native';
import STYLE from './styles';

import Images from '../../../../resources/Images';

export default class OwnMarker extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        this.state = {
            // HACK
            initialRender: true
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <Image 
                style={STYLE.marker} 
                source={Images.own_marker}
                resizeMethod="resize"
                // HACK
                onLayout={() => this.setState({ initialRender: false })}
                key={`${this.state.initialRender}`}
            />
        );
    }
}
```